# Extended glob functionality with arithmetic comparison

Tags: language-agnostic, glob

I have a couple use cases where I'd like to be able to declaratively specify a set of files which may have numbers in various locations in the path (in other words, where the number(s) are may vary between specifications but is known to me), and it would be useful to be able to specify conditions on the range of those numbers (e.g. between 2 and 21). I know it's possible to specify number ranges in regular expressions, but it's clumsy and error-prone, especially when compensating for things like '01' versus '1'.

My question is, does anyone know of any language or library that provides similar functionality? This kind of thing seems generic enough to be useful, but I can't recall seeing anything like it, and initial Googling hasn't turned anything up. The most common approach (I think I've used it before, actually) seems to be using regex groups and then processing those with whatever programming language you're using, but that kind of one-off solution isn't really satisfying.

Here's an example of what I might be looking for:

```
'/base_path/section/(?<n>\d{2})/subsection/(?<i>\d+)/.+' with 3 < n <= 9 and i < 100
```

This would return, for example,

```
/base_path/section/04/subsection/99/*
/base_path/section/09/subsection/000/*
```

but not

```
/base_path/section/01/subsection/0/*
```

or

```
/base_path/section/05/subsection/01000/*
```

### Use Case

The main use case I'm looking at right now, is that I would like to be able to divide a collection of files into two or more groups to be processed separately, partly based on a section number that occurs in the middle of the path. This is in the context of running some NLP experiments in various configurations, and I'd like to be able to declaratively specify which files to work with in a flexible manner so that I don't go crazy trying to make sure the right files are being used every time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know AWK is the way to go in this case.

Example:

```
echo '/base_path/section/456/subsection/99/' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } /\/base_path\/section\/[0-9]+\/subsection\/[0-9]+/ { if (($4 >= 400) && ($4 < 1000) && ($6 < 100)) print $0 }'
```

This will print the example path.

Comment: AWK is certainly a good solution, but it is a bit more verbose and less flexible than I might prefer. I don't think it will work with things like "/some/path/01 title.ogg", for instance.

Comment: I should add that your answer would work with my current use case. My main issue is that I would like a solution that more clearly states my intention to, say, "select files where this number is in this range and then do something to them".